# Was George Wallace's American Independent party (1968) "the same party" as Strom Thurmond's Dixiecrat party (1948)?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, political-history, political-party

The party that nominated George Wallace for president in 1968 [(the American Independent Party)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Independent_Party) seems very similar to the [State's Rights Democratic Party (aka. Dixiecrat)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixiecrat) that nominated Strom Thurmond for the presidency in 1948.

Were they 'the same party' separated by twenty years? Did they have the same ideology? Did they attract the same voters? Did they have any of the same people in leadership positions?

If not, what were the important differences between the two parties?

Comment: Please source all quotes ('the same party')

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question going to political science theory.

Comment: @SamuelRussell and why on Earth would a specific branch of history be off-topic? O_O

Comment: Last time I checked political science and history were separate disciplines, and political history doesn't attempt the kind of theorising you're demanding of it.  There's a perfectly good politics stackexchange by the way.

Comment: This is a history question, unless history is only recounting facts with no analysis. 'The same party' is not a quote, just a shorthand way of saying two separate organisations with the same ideas.

Comment: This is a history question, unless Bernard Bailyn's [Ideological Origins of the American Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ideological_Origins_of_the_American_Revolution), Lee Benson's The Concept of Jacksonian Democracy, and Daniel Walker Howe's [Political Culture of the American Whigs aren't works of history](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Political_Culture_of_the_American_Wh.html?id=gKtw_tbLWbcC).

Comment: @SamuelRussell "political science" != "political history". History is history is history. Not complicated.

Comment: At least for me, the last question is better than the title.  "Were they the same party" is judgmental, "What were the important differences between X & Y" is more analytical.  Does anyone else think that would improve?

Comment: Fine by me. I'm asking specifically about the ideological differences

Comment: The modified question seems to be more political history than political theory now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dixiecrats and the AIP were not really the same party, because they were led differently. But they had somewhat the same ideologies, geographies and voters.

The Dixiecrats were led by [Strom Thurmond,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strom_Thurmond) an aristocrat. He was pro-business and particularly popular among business owners in the coastal regions the south, and won his native South Carolina, plus the Gulf states of Alabama, Mississippi, and Louisiana in the 1948 Presidential election.

The AIP was led by [Governor George Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Wallace) of Alabama, who was a champion of the poor white (often union) working man. There are some authorities that believe that Wallace's racism was less a reflection of his personal beliefs than a matter of political expediency. His career took off (among white voters) when he started using anti-black rhetoric. In his 1968 Presidential campaign, Wallace won the three Gulf states, plus Georgia and Arkansas. Interestingly, he did not win South Carolina, which Thurmond held for Nixon.

In a "forced choice," Thurmond much preferred the (post 1964) Republican party to the Democrats, and eventually became a Republican. Wallace ran on a third party ticket saying "There's not a dime's worth of difference" between the two major ones.

So the two parties were not the same, even though they were both based in the deep South and were anti civil rights.

Comment: Thank you. Would be interesting to know what thurmond and other former Dixiecrats had to say about the AIP.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part yes, as their fundamental issue in both cases was support for segregation and white supremecy.

They were a bit different in theory, in that the AIP was founded as a conservative (far right) party that then courted southern whites, while the Dixiecrats were formed out of the southern Democratic party. However, in practice they both drew all their strength in their best years from the same sources. The Dixecrats won Louisiana, Mississippi, Alabama, and *South Carolina* (and one EV from Tennesse) [in 1948](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_1948), while [in 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_1968) the AIP won *Arkansas*, Louisiana, Mississippi, Alabama, and *Georgia*.